# Downvoted the answer without a valid reason

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Someone downvoted my answer, *[jQuery add class to active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503862/jquery-add-class-to-active-tab/26503929#26503929)*, without a valid reason. How do I know who downvoted it or for what reason it was downvoted?

Comment: For what it's worth (I wasn't involved with that question), [the initial revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26503929/1) of your answer only consisted in a short sentence and a link. You added code to flesh it out six minutes later. The downvote may very well have been cast during that time (I know I would have done so).

Comment: Even then, the answer doesn't add anything new. It's practically identical to the answer above it, except with less detail.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - it was, reputation history shows downvote came directly after the original answer was posted, before any code was edited in. FGITW backfires sometimes.

Comment: Ok, I got it...

Comment: Did someone [lose their keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-down-voting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) again? Wish he'd tie them down!

Comment: It should be reworded to fit the rules in the help center.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All voting on Stack Overflow is anonymous and we don't ask people to justify their votes.

You can't find out who voted on your posts or why they voted the way they did.

Have you considered that your answer might be wrong?

It was probably because your initial version was nothing more than a sentence and a link to another site:

> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26503929/1

This is not a "good" answer. Answers should be self contained and self explanatory - your initial version was neither.

Comment: Answer is not wrong.

Comment: [maybe it was too short?](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26503929/1)